# How to get control back from a php script to my main page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a javascript code in my main HTML page Smartmeter.html by which I am displaying meter data which is getting changed every 5s.

Now I need to insert this meter data which is getting changed in the javascript function into mysql via php every 30s.

Means I need to stay on the Smartmeter.html page as the javascript function is getting executed 5s and in the meantime also insert this meter data(variable--target) into mysql every 30s.

How can I achieve this? Can someone help me with some code or suggestions.

My Smartmeter.html page:

```html
    <html>
<head></head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=dynamic;
var target=100;
function dynamic()
{
  var1=Math.random();
  target=target + var1 * 1000; 
  target=Math.round(target);
  if(target>123457)
  {
    target=15647;
  }
  document.getElementById('hidden').value = target;
  func();
}


function func()
{
  //configuration of the reading displayed
  var primary = document.getElementById("d").getElementsByClassName("imge")[0].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];
  primary.innerHTML=target;

  alert('test');
  document.forms["myForm"].submit();

  // window.location.href = "http://localhost/SUA/Data_insertion.php?target=" + target;
  setTimeout(dynamic, 5000);
}

</script>

<body>

<style>

.imge
{
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: 30%;
margin-top: -150px;
margin-left: -150px;
}

h2{ 

position: absolute; 
top: 116px; 
left: 165px; 
width: 100%; 

}
p
{
position: absolute; 
top: 120px; 
left: 250px; 
width: 100%; 

}

input {
display: inline-block;
float: bottom;
}

</style>

<body bgcolor="#BDBDBD">
  <form action="Data_insertion.php" method="post" id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="reading" value=""><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

  <div id="d">
    <div class="imge">
      <img src="meter.jpg" width="450" height="350" alt="" />
      <h2>1234578  </h2>
      <p><font size="5">kWh</font></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is jQuery allowed? If it is allowed I have an simple answer (via ajax). If not there is a long answer (also via ajax :) )

Comment: Ok, I see the jQuery include, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-Solution:

```
function submitValue(url, key, value){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            key: key,
            value: value
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert("done: "+data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });             
}
```

Process your data like this:

```
<?php
    switch($_POST['key']){
        case "voltage": setVoltage($_POST['value']); break;
        case "current": setCurrent($_POST['value']); break;
        default: http_response_code(404); die()      break;
    }
    echo "successful set ".$_POST['key']." to ".$_POST['value'];

    function setVoltage($voltage){
        /* sql magic */
    }
    function setCurrent($current){
        /* sql magic */
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**

For your Problem this simple version should work:

```
function sendValue(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Data_insertion.php',
        data: {
            reading: target
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert('done');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    }); 
}

function init(){
    // remove this line from function func()
    setTimeout(dynamic, 5000);
    setTimeout(sendValue, 30000);
}
```

and Change

```
<body bgcolor="#BDBDBD">
<form action="Data_insertion.php" method="post" id="myForm">
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="reading" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

to

```
<body bgcolor="#BDBDBD" onLoad="init()">
<button onClick="sendValue(target)">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I am new to ajax..what should i provide in url,key,value?

Comment: That's ok..but as mentioned in the question I need to execute the js functions-dynamic() and func() every 5s.Also side by side I want to send this ajax request say every 30s i.e submit the form every 30s.Can u help with that?

Comment: You still have every thing you need :)

I've updated the answer once again.